# Conditions under which the preimage of the image of a set is equal to the set

Tags: functions

Let $X, Y$ be sets, $S \subseteq X$ and $f: X \to Y$ be a function.
I understand that, generally speaking, the preimage of the image of $S$ - i.e., $f^{-1}(f(S))$ - is not equal to $S$. But I was trying to identify special circumstances under which this identity would hold. I came up with this:

$f^{-1}(f(S)) = S \hspace{1cm} \leftrightarrow \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in X \setminus S: \hspace{0.3cm} f(x) \notin f(S)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Thank you!!! (:

Comment: Please delete the question or answer it yourself and accept your answer so the question does not linger on the unanswered queue.

Comment: I've now read otherwise in Tao's book on Analysis. There, he claims that f^{-1}(f(S)) = S iff f is injective. That seems different from what I've proposed here. My thought was that f needn't be injective, as long as only distinct x *within* S may be assigned the same y. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are right. I'm pretty sure Tao is too, so I suspect there is more context in Tao. I haven't read your proof. When you are used to reading and writing proofs you won't need that many small formal steps to construct a convincing argument.

Comment: Tao claims this only in the context of a short exercise statement. I quote:
"Let f: X -> Y be a function from one set X to another set Y. Show that f^{-1}(f(S)) = S for every S \subseteq X if and only if f is injective."

It's too bad that mathematicians find a proof as I wrote it so tedious. For me, the very thing that gives me pleasure in writing out proofs is leaving nothing to intuition and instead making explicit every little nuance. Also, it would have been helpful for me in learning math to have such "tedious" proofs at my disposal. But yes, I'm sure this changes through practice. (:

Comment: The difference between Tao's assertion and yours is "for every $S$". It's good to be able to fill in all the details when you're learning to write proofs. If you do that for longer and more complicated arguments both you and your reader lose the thread of what matters - the clever steps rather than the routine ones.

Comment: OK, I think I've finally got it. Tao's claim is: $\forall X,S: S \subseteq X \to f^{-1}(f(S)) = S \iff f$ is injective. My claim is: $\forall X,S: S \subseteq X \land f^{-1}f(S)) = S \iff \forall x \in X \setminus S: f(x) \notin f(S)$. This interaction was extremely helpful for me, thank you for all your patience. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case someone else has a similar issue. Please also notice the comments on my original post.

Yes, this is correct. I'll post my proof in order to contribute something, but I give no guarantees that my proof is correct.

[image]

[image]